# randomising operators visual basic

Tags: vb.net, operators

I want my program (visual basic) to randomly select times (*) or divide (/) and for that to be used as an operator in an equation later in the program. I haven't started as this is for the declaration of variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide any code so there can be many solutions. You only have two operators, so I think the best way to go would be to just use conditions. The basics are to use the `Random` class, and an `If` or a `Case`.

The code can look like this:

```
Function DoSomeOperation(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double, Optional ByRef op As String = "") As Double
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Select Case rnd.Next(0, 2)
        Case 1
            op = "/"
            Return a / b
        Case Else
            op = "*"
            Return a * b
    End Select
End Function
```

This code will return the operation result, and optionally the operation used in the `op` parameter. The `rnd.Next(0, 2)` statement returns either `0` or `1` (because the maxValue `2`, is an exclusive upper bound).

*In real life you should probably check the result doesn't exceed the `Double` limits, and do a `try..catch`.

Example of the function use in a Console app:

```
    Dim a As Double = 8
    Dim b As Double = 2
    Dim op As String = ""
    Dim result As Double = DoSomeOperation(a, b, op)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2} = {3}", a, op, b, result))
    Console.ReadKey()
    'Output: 8 * 2 = 16 or 8 / 2 = 4
```

### Addition

To answer @WickedJDG comment, if you want `a` and `b` randomly selected between 1 and 12, you can use this function:

```
Function DoSomeRandomOperation(Optional ByRef a As Double = 0, Optional ByRef b As Double = 0, Optional ByRef op As String = "") As Double
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    a = rnd.Next(1, 13)
    b = rnd.Next(1, 13)
    Select Case rnd.Next(0, 2)
        Case 1
            op = "/"
            Return a / b
        Case Else
            op = "*"
            Return a * b
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Where in your code at the top would you place random selection of a and b between 1 and 12? @Joel-Coehoorn

Comment: Sorry, I meant @dePatinkin

Comment: You should create just one instance of `Random` rather than a new one each time you call the function.

Comment: This is just an example of a function, that doesn't include the class declaration. Anyhow, I wouldn't create a global instance of `Random` just for this one function.